# Android: How to get return result from activity when calling from Fragment?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have a Fragment that calls another Activity using:

```
ProductEditionMaintenanceActivity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("productCode", productCode);
extras.putInt("productEditionID", 0);
intent.putExtras(extras);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

and return from the activity:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

I tried to use the following in the Fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    //Do something
}
```

However, I am guessing the intent created passed the reference of the parent Activity of the Fragment therefore onActivityResult on the Fragment does not get called. 
If that is the case, what do I need to do so the fragment get the result from the callee Activity?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The fragments `onActivityResult` will get called AFTER the host activities `onActivityResult` as long as `super.onActivityResult` is called from the host activity. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6147919/552902 for more detail